# Heroku + react + next.js + wordpress - Syntax error, but what do I do?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, next.js

I'm using react + next.js + wordpress api (wp is hosted somewhere else). The _document.js is where the project all starts. So, in my `procfile`, I have:

`web: node pages/_document.js`

But it doesn't seem like Heroku likes that underscore. Can someone please help??

### Heroku Logs

```
...

 2017-08-02T23:25:58.694324+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node pages/_document.js`
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609211+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/pages/_document.js:1
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609234+00:00 app[web.1]: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609235+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                               ^^^^^^
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609236+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609237+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609238+00:00 app[web.1]:     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609238+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609239+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609240+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609240+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609241+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609242+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609241+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609243+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.609243+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.670350+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.673110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
 2017-08-02T23:26:00.655633+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
 2017-08-02T23:26:04.035702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node pages/_document.js`
 2017-08-02T23:26:06.079168+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
 2017-08-02T23:26:05.997361+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                               ^^^^^^
....
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "author": "me",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.1.7",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "lru-cache": "4.0.2",
    "next": "2.0.0-beta.16",
    "nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "styled-components": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "now-start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Node still doesn't support [ES6 module syntax](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html). Use [CommonJS](https://webpack.github.io/docs/commonjs.html) instead. For that, replace all your:

```
export default XXX; // <-- ES6 export syntax (NO)
```

and:

```
import XXX from 'xxx'; // <-- ES6 import syntax (NO)
```

with:

```
module.exports = XXX; // <-- CommonJS export syntax (YES)
```

and

```
const XXX = require('xxx'); // <-- CommonJS import syntax (YES)
```

Hope this helps!

---

**EDIT**

More specifically, your Heroku logs is complaining about this line:

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
```

Change it to:

```
const Document = require('next/document');
const {Head, Main, NextScript} = require('next/document');
```